# maintaining a multi-project internal svn and an external git repository

Tags: git

Okay, we have a big internal subversion system where multiple projects are hosted. Part of this project is exported as an open source git repository on github.

There are dependencies and unnecessarily complex directory structure that were not straightforward to export, so I wrote a shell script that selectively collects the relevant source code into a more external user friendly form.

But since then, we had a few updates related to the project, and keeping both repositories in sync is becoming a hassle. The github repository is not yet forked once, so it's only us who are updating the source tree for now.

Is there an elegant solution to this kind of situations? I want the git repository to be automatically synchronized with the svn commits, but there's a correspondence problem.